# Замена события click на document.ready у обработчика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как повесить обработчик `$('document').on('ready', handler)` вместо `$('#foot-carousel').on('click', handler);`?

JS:

```
$('#foot-carousel').on('click', '.remove-item', function() { 
    if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
        $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
    } else {
        $('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').removeItem($(this));
        $(".fixed-bottom").show();
    };
});
```

Comment: Предпологаю,  что Вам нужно чтобы текущая анонимная фунция выполнялась по событю ready(как только загрузится страница)?

Comment: @Regent имеется ввиду, чтобы обработчик срабатывал не по клику, а по готовности дом дерева `ready`

Comment: @koks_rs да, вы правы

Comment: она будет отличаться от `$(document).ready(function($) {..}` или это одно и тоже?

Comment: Всё так же: `$(document).ready(function() { if ( ... });`

Comment: получается одно и тоже... а если мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы срабатывало условие, но оно всегда отображает else даже если условие истинно?
if ( $(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty") ) {
  $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
 }
 else {
  $(".fixed-bottom").show();
 };

Comment: @Вася, значит элемент <li>  при загрузке не имеет класса empty. Либо вообще не существует.

Comment: @koks_rs я уже ниже отвечал, что <li> не отображается в исходном коде страницы (т.к. подгружается через виджет вордпресса), но виден в инструментах разработчика

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

```
//Данная функция выполняется, когда объектная модель готова к использованию
$(document).ready(function () {
            if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").length == 0 || $(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
                $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
            }
            else {
                $(".fixed-bottom").show();
            }
 });
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
 //Более опытные программисты предпочли бы скорее написать немного подругому. Покороче.
 $(function () {
            if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").length == 0 || $(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
                $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
            }
            else {
                $(".fixed-bottom").show();
            }
 });
```

Comment: Я, конечно, понимаю, что заданный вопрос автора несколько странен сам по себе, но всё же есть проблема: `$(this)` здесь смотрится не к месту. Я не сразу заметил это в исходном коде. В исходном коде `this` был `.remove-item`, а тут - `window`.

Comment: @Regent, я просто бездумно скопировал код задающего вопрос. В любом случае, удалять что-то сразу при загрузке, то что удалилось бы по клику было бы странно.

Comment: @koks_rs я правильно понимаю, что $(function () {..} нужно помещать внутрь блока $(document).ready(function($) {..} иначе условие не выполняется и переходит сразу к else ?

Comment: @Regent теперь я просто выполняю это условие:
`$(function () {
        if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
            $(".fixed-bottom").hide();
        }
else {
$(".fixed-bottom").show().fadeTo( "slow");
 };
});`

Comment: @Вася, нет не правильно.  `$(function () {..}` и `$(document).ready(function($) {..}` это одно и тоже. Просто разный стиль написания. К тому же они должны быть помещены в не функуций. Можете просто вначале скрипта разместить. А если не выполняется условие это другой вопрос совсем.Вы приведите нам исходный HTML, тогда можно что-то ответить.

Comment: koks_rs - сюда [http://jsfiddle.net/ligisayan/rm07jdkv/] условие тогда не выполняется

Comment: @Вася, Это нормально, потому что если на момент, когда страница загрузилась, Ваш список пуст, то условие не выполняется потому что $(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li") ничего не вернет. Ведь $(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li") ищет элементы <li>  в вашем списке, правильно? А их там нет.

Comment: @koks_rs нет, не правильно - они там есть, в том-то и беда..скажем их  3 штуки - мы одну удаляем, страница перезагружается, в списке остаются 2, но они не отображаются. И, если быть внимательным, то я говорю, что условие не выполняется и при любых раскладах (есть ли или их нет) отображается вот это `$(".fixed-bottom").show();`

Comment: если мы помещаем $(function () {..} внутрь блока $(document).ready(function($) {..} условие более-менее выполняется (по крайней мере блок отображается почти всегда, когда это нужно), за 2мя исключениями

Comment: @koks_rs _Видишь суслика? 
— Нет.
— И я не вижу. А он есть!_

Comment: @Вася, давайте уже весь код в студию. Гадаем по звездам. Либо удостоверьтесь, что вы загружаете список до срабатывания on ready функции.

Comment: @Regent печаль, но это так.. например вот такое условие `if (!$(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {
 $(".fixed-bottom").show();
}`помещенное в `$(document).ready(function($) {..}` отображается ВСЕГДА при любых раскладах, даже когда в .fixed-bottom .cart_list li есть класс empty...

Comment: @koks_rs в смысле весь? весь код wordpress+woocommerce? список изначально пуст, при клике на кнопки он наполняется элементами, когда жмем на кнопку удалить - он удаляет элемент. настоящая проблема возникает в тот, момент, когда жмем удалить - нас перебрасывает на др страницу, но клик не успевает обработаться, поэтому при перезагрузке страницы список с элементами остается, а у выпадающего меню условие не выполняется

Comment: @Вася фокус: [пример с классом empty](http://jsfiddle.net/ftvL0429/). Тот же [пример без класса empty](http://jsfiddle.net/ftvL0429/1/).

Comment: @Regent в доказательство, что я вас не обманываю - привожу код исходной моей страницы[http://fiddle.jshell.net/z5r2zbpd/]
я кажется, начинаю догонять - обработчик `$(document).ready(function($) {..}` проходится по исходному коду страницы, где не отображается инфа с вордпресовского виджета! хотя через дебагер я его вижу: `<ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
  <li class="empty">Корзина пуста.</li>
</ul>`

Comment: у думал в этом случае вот это сработает `if (!$(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li")) {
  $(".fixed-bottom").show();
 }`, но нет...

Comment: а в инструментах обработчика видно так: [http://s017.radikal.ru/i430/1506/96/871bd8b0e15f.png]

Comment: @Вася, $(document).ready(function () {} срабатывает скорее всего до того как в список попадут элементы. Попробуйте преставить в голове жизненый цикл страницы.

Comment: @Вася во-первых, я никогда не говорил, что вы нас обманываете. Но я говорил, что без воспроизводимого примера можно только сидеть, махать руками и гадать. Во-вторых, я не понял к чему был этот fiddle - там нет ни одного элемента `<li>`. В-третьих, `document.ready` происходит тогда, когда страница (то, что на ней было изначально. То, что отдано сервером) загружена. Если на ней что-то меняется позже, то к `document.ready` это не имеет никакого отношение - повторно это событие вызвано не будет.

Comment: @Regent "я не понял к чему был этот fiddle - там нет ни одного элемента <li>" да, фидл был как раз к тому, что в исходном коде `<li>` не отображаются! а в инст разработчика, что на фотке - там видно, что есть li с классом empty после загрузки страницы, из чего я сделал предположение, что `document.ready` точно также просматривает страницу и никаких li не видит!

Comment: а вот так `if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list:has(li)")) {
  $(".fixed-bottom").show();
 }` нельзя проследить, если предполагать, что элементов li как бы нету?

Comment: @Вася событие `document.ready`, как правило, происходит до того, как HTML-структура начинает меняться с помощью JS. И уж точно нельзя на него рассчитывать как на событие, которое произойдёт ровно после того, как какой-то JS-код что-то поменяет в HTML.

Comment: @Вася Тогда должно быть `if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list:has(li)").length > 0) { $(".fixed-bottom").show(); }`

Comment: @Regent и это, к сожалению, тоже не срабатывает..может, нужно использовать .ajaxSuccess() или .ajaxComplete() ?

Comment: @Вася вы всё подряд перебираете, что ли? Тогда имеет смысл сесть и внимательно поизучать документацию к jQuery, а также что, как и когда происходит на странице.

Comment: @Regent к сожалению, здесь нужен большой опыт и простое прочтение документации для контретного решения задачи ничего не даст..

Comment: @Вася я же вам не предлагаю наизусть её выучить. Я и сам периодически заглядываю в неё. Но важно понимать общие концепции. Потому что пример вы предоставить по известным причинам не можете, мы поэтому помочь не можем, а вы сидите, гадаете. Непродуктивно получается в итоге.

Comment: @Вася, я перечитал все коментарии и немного поменял условия проверки в ответе, попробуйте сейчас. Или на вашем фидле http://jsfiddle.net/rm07jdkv/5/

Comment: @koks_rs к сожалению, все равно пишет при загрузке каждый раз "скрыто"..

Comment: ок @Regent но давайте лучше на живом примере разберем - здесь лайф превью моей темы (все аналогично)[http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/22/] набираем товар в корзину и потом вверху корзины на крестик товар удаляем. после этого происходит ajax обработка, визуально мы остаемся на главной странице, но ссылка приобретает вид `\?removed_item=1`

Answer (score 0):

Не вникая в подробности кода, может, просто по загрузке вызывать событие клика?

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $( "#foot-carousel" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/f94z2k5j/) поиграть.

Comment: А что будет, по идее, в обработчике клика на месте `$(this)` `window` или `undefined`?

Comment: @koks_rs в обработчике `$("#foot-carousel").on("click", function() {  ... });` `this` указывает на `#foot-carousel`, в том числе и при генерации события через `$( "#foot-carousel" ).trigger("click");`

Comment: @Sergiks стоп, так ничего же не работает?

Comment: @Вася пуск. в свежем FireFox работает: кнопка сразу становится «Можно уже не нажимать» – т.к. сработал ненастоящий клик по событию `document`'а.

Comment: @Sergiks да, становится - а почему не настоящий?

Comment: Потому, что мы это событие вызвали с помощью `.trigger()`, а не мышкой кликнули по кнопке.

Comment: @Sergiks так, и как это может помочь моей беде - сорри, не догоняю пока

Comment: @Вася, как я понял, вы хотите, чтобы что-то, обычно происходящее только по нажатию на кнопку, у вас стало срабатывать сразу по загрузке страницы – событию `$('document').on('ready')`. Или всё с точностью до наоборот?

Comment: @Sergiks скорее в точность наоборот) мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке отображался блок, если в нем есть какие-то элементы и не отображался, если нет